vCenter 7 script to edit/delete VM
I have a cloning task set on vCenter 7.x, it runs every day.
it clones "machine A" with name "machine B"
My problem is that on the next day, it wont clone as there is already a "Machine B" in the environment.
To my understanding I can access vCenter VM via SSH, and set up a script to perform the following actions.
Detect names for all VMs
If "Machine B" detected in Name
 create dictionary of "Machine B" and created "date"
Rename "Machine B"s as "Machine B_(date)"
if "Machine B" is older than 3 days, "read from name" compare with current time
  then erase VM
otherwise
  keep it

I would like to know if/how this script can be created?
I imagine I need to run the script once and keep it running, problem is that I do not know the scripting language, from my research, vCenter runs in PHOTON OS https://vmware.github.io/photon/assets/files/html/3.0/, a subdivision of Linux, but the commands I can find do not cover what I need.
greatly appreciate your input. or if vCenter is not the best, then an alternative, or if script is not the best then an alternative on the UI.

It looks as if you are asking 4 questions here. Have a look here, in particular to the answer given by user Sheshank S.

I have paraphrase it, the question is about the script..

To find someone for writing a program for you, Stackoverflow is not the right place. you could post such a request at freelancer; I've never tried it myself, but have been told that this platform even works for tiny "pocket" projects. If you want to stick with Stackoverflow, you would pick the first step from your list (detect all VMs), and try to do it by yourself. Then post the code you have tried, and explain in what respect it doesn't work. You will most likely get helpful answers to improve it. Then, do the same with the next step ("create dictionary").

One more point: You say that you don't know bash. Why don't you implement it in one of the programming languages you already know. I don't see why you would need bash here.

I need to clarify that I do not want a person to write a script, I need a scripting language, I do not know what commands to use.. it would be like writing Python commands in a shell script without links. Also I can not just place random "commands" here, it may erase my environment and I would have to recreate everything from scratch.

One more point, I know bash, I do not need bash, I do not know if bash commands will work in PHOTON OS.

NOTE VMWare was purchased by Broadcom, so if the links do not work is because they have moved the documentation across.
NOTE the links to download vCenter 7 have changed because of this too.
----------------------------------------Information HERE----------------------------------------
there are several aspects to solve this problem, but first, the scripting language.
PHOTON OS as defined in the link from my question has a limited set of commands that can be used. Upon using SSH to enter vCenter 7.x VM there are 3 lists of commands.

API commands like "com.vmware.appliance.version1.services.list" as defined in this VMWare Link generally used to see the health or config of the vCenter environment, Also in 2. vCenter PDF link

Plug-Ins Commands like "com.vmware.ping" as defined in this vCenter PDF generally used as administrative tools. list of 22 options

limited shell commands like "pwd [-LP]" mostly as defined in this GNU link, PHOTON list is limited to 84 options


in detail
job_spec [&]
(( expression ))
. filename [arguments]
:
[ arg... ]
[[ expression ]]
alias [-p] [name[=value] ... ]
bg [job_spec ...]
bind [-lpsvPSVX] [-m keymap] [-f filename] [-q name] [-u name] [-r key>
break [n]
builtin [shell-builtin [arg ...]]
caller [expr]
case WORD in [PATTERN [| PATTERN]...) COMMANDS ;;]... esac
cd [-L|[-P [-e]] [-@]] [dir]
command [-pVv] command [arg ...]
compgen [-abcdefgjksuv] [-o option] [-A action] [-G globpat] [-W wordl>
complete [-abcdefgjksuv] [-pr] [-DE] [-o option] [-A action] [-G globp>
compopt [-o|+o option] [-DE] [name ...]
continue [n]
coproc [NAME] command [redirections]
declare [-aAfFgilnrtux] [-p] [name[=value] ...]
dirs [-clpv] [+N] [-N]
disown [-h] [-ar] [jobspec ... | pid ...]
echo [-neE] [arg ...]
enable [-a] [-dnps] [-f filename] [name ...]
eval [arg ...]
exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments ...]] [redirection ...]
exit [n]
export [-fn] [name[=value] ...]
export -p
false
fc [-e ename] [-lnr] [first] [last]
fc -s [pat=rep] [command]         
fg [job_spec]
for NAME [in WORDS ... ] ; do COMMANDS; done
for (( exp1; exp2; exp3 )); do COMMANDS; done
function name { COMMANDS ; }
function name () { COMMANDS ; }
getopts optstring name [arg]
hash [-lr] [-p pathname] [-dt] [name ...]
help [-dms] [pattern ...]
history [-c] [-d offset] [n]
history -anrw [filename] 
history ->
if COMMANDS; then COMMANDS; [ elif COMMANDS; then COMMANDS; ]... [ el>
jobs [-lnprs] [jobspec ...]
jobs -x command [args]
kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... 
kill -l>
let arg [arg ...]
local [option] name[=value] ...
logout [n]
mapfile [-d delim] [-n count] [-O origin] [-s count] [-t] [-u fd] [-C>
popd [-n] [+N | -N]
printf [-v var] format [arguments]
pushd [-n] [+N | -N | dir]
pwd [-LP]
read [-ers] [-a array] [-d delim] [-i text] [-n nchars] [-N nchars] [>
readarray [-n count] [-O origin] [-s count] [-t] [-u fd] [-C callback>
readonly [-aAf] [name[=value] ...]
readonly -p
return [n]
select NAME [in WORDS ... ;] do COMMANDS; done
set [-abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option-name] [--] [arg ...]
shift [n]
shopt [-pqsu] [-o] [optname ...]
source filename [arguments]
suspend [-f]
test [expr]
time [-p] pipeline
times
trap [-lp] [[arg] signal_spec ...]
true
type [-afptP] name [name ...]
typeset [-aAfFgilnrtux] [-p] name[=value] ...
ulimit [-SHabcdefiklmnpqrstuvxPT] [limit]
umask [-p] [-S] [mode]
unalias [-a] name [name ...]
unset [-f] [-v] [-n] [name ...]
until COMMANDS; do COMMANDS; done
variables - Names and meanings of some shell variables
wait [-n] [id ...]
while COMMANDS; do COMMANDS; done
{ COMMANDS ; }

if this has changed then use

help api list
help pi list
shell help

they mention "Use man -k' or info' to find out more about commands not in this list."
While exploring solutions I discovered

DCLI (Datacenter Command-Line Interfaces) which also has a list of usable commands to work with the VMs.

here an introduction to it, Getting Started with Datacenter CLI
here the PDF version DCLI User's Guide
note that while in DCLI, every command will prompt a user and password verification. always use user "administrator@vsphere.local" and the password you ser while deploying the vCenter VM.
there is a way to add credentials, for example, save credentials and list VMs vCenter is monitoring.
dcli +server XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX +username 'administrator@vsphere.local' +credstore-add +skip-server-verification com vmware vcenter 

next time the command can be shorter
dcli +server XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX +skip-server-verification com vmware vcenter vm list

----------------------------------------SOLUTION HERE----------------------------------------
While these four can be explored. I do not have time. so I found option 5.
I have realised that is better to run script in ESXi rather than use SSH from vCenter VM and run commands there. Moreover , all files associated to the VM should change as "just changing the VM Display name" still crashes the daily task.

SSH to ESXi, where all VMs and files are stored.


enable SSH in ESXi
use SSH to access the ESXi server
go to folder var
create a file with vi rename.sh
implement steps as script as defined on this Broadcom Link
give permissions to file
keep it running with a while loop
disable SSH

as commands from previous steps
cd /var
vi rename.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo '-----------------------------------------------------'
vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms
cd /vmfs/volumes/<your Datastore>/
...
...
chmod ### rename.sh
./rename.sh

I have found these steps to automatically run my script  ESXi bash script ... 
in detail
cd /var/spool/cron/crontabs
vi root
...

*/5  *    *   *   *    /location of the script/ like /vmfs/script.sh
...

save and exit

/bin/kill $(cat /var/run/crond.pid)
/usr/lib/vmware/busybox/bin/busybox crond

other useful commands for ESXI on this Broadcom common virtual machine-related tasks with command-line utilities
